# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe For MSSQL DB

Tags: java, sql-server

I'm suffering from

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe Exception
```

after I disconnect the network (by removing the network cable) and plug the network cable back in. This error occurs for MSSQL DB and connect using JTurbo driver. I want to auto-reconnect after a connection is established. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. You have a network failure, i.e. a failure in a distributed system, which can therefore be a partial failure. You don't know whether the transaction has completed or not. You can't hide that under the covers of an auto-retry. The application needs to know about it.

Comment: It's an application problem, not a programming problem. You would have to ask the application designers what they want to do about it.